# Group values inside a loop and return it as an object with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

New to typescript so not sure how to map values inside a loop. I am running a function which does some logic which returns a number(nothing special). This function will be called in a other function to return 2 values, 1. is a number 2. is a string.

```
export class matrix {

     public pattern!: {[key: string]: number[]};

     // function will be called in a loop in a different function
     public setPattern(data: number, category: string): void {

         // does some logic here and set row as a value
         const row = 10;// random value of course
 
         this.pattern[category].push(row);// not working of course
     
     } 
}
     
//output should be like this  
{
    "some category": [10,55,4,53,1],
    "more rows": [1,2,8]
}
```

Comment: are you trying to create an object or an array ? Because pattern looks like an object so it's normal that you can't push element inside

Comment: There is a typo you have added extra `R`, `catergory: string` here `this.pattern[category]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not working when array is not initialized

Add this before pushing new element

```
if(this.pattern[category] == undefined) this.pattern[category] = []
```

And then after array is initialized push new element to it

```
this.pattern[category].push(row);
```

Also make sure that pattern object is initialized

```
public pattern!: {[key: string]: number[]}; = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first call, the pattern is undefined, it'll not be able to add the key to undefined `this.pattern[catergory]`.

```
export class matrix {
    public pattern: {[key: string]: number[]} = {};
    public setPattern(data: number, catergory: string): void {
        const row = 10;// random value of course
        this.pattern[catergory].push(row);// not working of course
    } 
}
```